# Error when implementing overloaded operator '<<' - C++

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm currently trying to overload the '<<' operator but keep receiving this error message:

> In function 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const :Linkedlist&)':
>   Linkedlist.cpp:148:34: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::operator<< [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, _Alloc = std::allocator](((std::basic_ostream&)((std::ostream*)outs)), ((const std::basic_string&)((const std::basic_string*)(& Node::node::fetchData()())))) << " "'
>   Linkedlist.cpp:142:15: note: candidate is: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Linkedlist&)

The overloaded operator function is declared as a friend member function in the Linkedlist implementation file because it will access a private member variable (head_ptr):

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outs, const Linkedlist& source)
{
    node* cursor;
    for(cursor = source.get_head(); cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor->fetchLink())
    {
        outs << cursor->fetchData() << " ";
    }

    return(outs);
}
```

This is the function prototype in the Linkedlist header file:

```
friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outs, const Linkedlist& source);
```

I've crawled the web and haven't been able to find a solution so far. Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Is your cursor->fetchData() returning a std::string? If so, you must `#include <string>`.
or, try

```
outs << cursor->fetchData().c_str() << " ";
```

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion for future posts that you might make: If you post parts of your code in your question, please post all relevant bits. Right now, it is not clear what `fetchData()` returns.

From the looks of it seems that `fetchData()` returns something which does not have an overload for `std::ostream::<<`.

When you output to a `std::ostream` instance, all components must have defined behaviour with it. For instance, in the example below, for `<<` to work with the instance of `A`, the operator has to either use `x` directly or `B` needs to define some behaviour where it pushes some values known to the standard `ostream` operator. Otherwise, you have to provide overloads for everything within the chain.

```cpp
class B
{
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const B& b);
int x = 10;

};

class A
{
private:
B b;
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const A& a);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const B& b)
{
   stream << b.x;
   return stream;
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const A& a)
{
   stream << a.b;
   return stream;
}
int main()
{
  A a;
  std::cout << a << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

My suspicion is that `fetchData()` returns a type that does not have an overload for the `<<` operator. This is why you see a failure.

Only 2 things that you can do

1. Make sure that the type returned by `fetchData()` has an overload for `<<`. C++ native and string types (in `<string>`) already have this feature. If it is a custom type, then you have to write a overload for that type.
2. Return a string from `fetchData`. That way you can utilise the `std::string` overload for `<<` in `<string>`.

As I said before, without knowing what `fetchData()` returns, it is hard to say what is wrong here.